# Migrate from old domain user profile to another profile under new trusted domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-profile, samba4, migration

i'm changing the domain from windows 2008R2 to samba4.2. 
now, is there any way to migrate the existing old domain user profile to new trusted domain in the fastest way?  i did changing the registry profilelist. but windows 8.1 having error on group policy client sign-in failed, therefore, any alternate way to doing it?

Regards,
MH

Comment: i found the answer as below URL 
http://superuser.com/questions/660602/windows-7-migrate-user-profile-to-another-computer-manually

Comment: Why would you stop using Active Directory?

Comment: basically is the cost concern for expanding users

Comment: Have you calculated the cost of supporting a SAMBA 4 infrastructure as you grow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

1. Created new_user account
2. Logged in as new_user to initialize profile
3. Rebooted
4. Logged in as Administrator and copied profile from old PC's hard
   drive to C:\Users\old_profile
5. Changed permissions of C:\Users\old_profile: Added new_user account
   with Full Access
6. Changed new_user's ProfileImagePath key in registry:
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList] to C:\Users\old_profile
7. Loaded hive C:\Users\old_profile\ntuser.dat and added new_user
   account with Full Access
8. Load hive
   C:\Users\old_profile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat
   and add new_user account with Full Access permissions.
9. Rebooted
10. Logged in as new_user